Is it correct to call a room with a bath a "toilet"?
In every country when speaking English, the room with a bath, bathtub, or shower is called a "bathroom". However, some people in Australia call this a "toilet", which is the standard term to describe a public room with just a toilet and sink in many countries when speaking English, though bathroom is understood too as sometimes in Australia, I hear people call this a bathroom too, though not as much as toilet. In small occassions, toilet is sometimes used in USA to describe the public toilet rooms too, but most will choose to call it a restroom, which I see written in shopping centres in Australia, but to be honest, when I hear people say "I need to go to the toilet", "I need to use the toilet", or "I need the toilet", it is hard to tell if they are referring to the room or the appliance.
From my experience, in Spanish-speaking countries, the term is "bano", which means "bathroom", and it is used for both rooms with a bath and with just a toilet and sink.
Would you say it is right to call a room with a bath or shower a "toilet"?
Also, since when did toilet become the term for this? Why not call it "sink" instead of the most disgusting appliance in a bathroom?
Lavatory remains my favorite word, and this word is used commonly in airlines from USA.

Completely off-topic, but "lavatory" was always one of my favorites as well. When I was a kid, I thought a "lavatory" was a room with lava in it. That was from my "dinosaurs and volcanos" phase. Imagine my disappointment upon learning a lavatory is just a room with a toilet in it. No lava.

Lavatory is the only one that makes sense for the public rooms that have just a toilet and sink.

Note, this is one term with strong regional variation! Any "right term" must be "for this particular country or even region."

Also: It's not clear, but I wonder whether your question is "Would you ever call a room that has no toilet, just washing facilities, a toilet"? I have a hard time imagining a room that has a bath or shower without a toilet, but no, one probably wouldn't.

One more red-herring observation: "toilet" might seem like the disgustingly direct term that other terms are euphemisms for. But the word itself came from French toilette, referring to a cloth and indirectly to the process of dressing and grooming.

I've pondered the fact that many euphemisms replace a direct or lowbrow word with an indirect or elevated one ("relieve oneself"), while many terms replace the direct term with something less direct to be offensive ("take a dump"), but that there is no "original or direct word" for the actual porcelain fixture that isn't either a euphemism (toilet, commode) or shock-value (crapper).

Allow me this comment: Do not go to someone's house (in the US) and say: May I used the restroom? restrooms in the US are found in public places, houses have bathrooms. So say: May I use the bathroom? Baño in Spanish is generic for going to the bathroom or restroom in either a private or public  space, respectively. Also, don't forget the slang: john (US) and loo (UK) and the head, not only used by sailors in both places. The funniest thing I have ever seen was on a Boston-NY bus line (Chinese owned) that said: lavoratorio. lavatory in British English means toilet (basin).

@GregBurghardt, The original meaning of "lavatory" is, a station for washing your hands. Plumbers and "kitchen and bath" renovators still use it in that way.

@Lambie, Last time I was in a Spanish speaking country, I asked, "¿Donde estan los servicios?"

It's not just regional variation.  In Architecture and Engineering, in [at least some regions of] the US "lavatory" is the sink fixture. (Not surprising since it means "a place to wash".)  I disagree partially with @Lambie about "restroom" in a US home. If someone asked me, it might seem overly formal but not wrong or offensive.  Bonus: Also in US Architecture/Engineering context, I have seen "WC" ("water closet") for the toilet fixture where in other contexts, WC might be the room.

"WC" is a nice, small abbreviation for a small room on a drawing.

@SolomonSlow Sure, sure, sure but Me voy al baño is often used to mean: I'm going to the bathroom.

@Theodore Calling a bathroom in a home a restroom is wrong since no one that lives in house would say that about their own bathroom. It is not formal or offensive; it's ignorant.

@Lambie This must be regional. While "restroom" wouldn't be the first word I'd reach for to describe the bathroom in someone's home, I wouldn't think twice about it if someone else used it. They have different connotations to me, but not nearly strong enough that I'd call it "ignorant" to use one in place of the other

Same can be said about calling a bathroom at home the toilet, which apparently some people in Australia even do.

When you write the room with a bath, bathtub, or shower is called a "bathroom",  how do those first two differ? That is, what is the intended distinction you're making between a bath and a bathtub in your list? So far as I am aware, the principal senses of the word bath are for (1) a bathroom, or for (2) a bathtub, or for (3) the act of bathing (no matter whether that means bathing oneself or something else).

I believe that the term "bathroom" can be used to refer to a room containing at least a bath or shower, and the "toilet" is the room where you can relieve yourself. I live in a country where it is very common to have combined toilet and bathroom in apartments, and separate ones are rare, so these terms are usually used interchangeably here, but that's not always the case and may depend on the context.

"bathroom" can mean EITHER bath/shower OR just toilet.  "toilet" can mean only toilet.

An old EL&U question “What is toilet" with pictures!. You can easily tell the poster was a non-native speaker but their confusion was understandable. It was closed as  duplicate of "Washroom", "restroom", "bathroom", "lavatory", "toilet" or "toilet room"

Related What's the word for a room for bath only? and Can we say "I'm going to the bathroom" to mean "I'm going to take a shower / bath"?

@tchrist I suppose something built directly into the floor would in very strict terms be a bath, but not a bathtub, since there’s no actual tub. I doubt anyone would uphold such a distinction in real life, though – I would certainly not hesitate to call it a bathtub, or even just a tub, even though there’s technically no tub.

@Janus In America, people would just call it a shower. Most people dont take baths in America as they take showers instead. They say bath, but never as a short form for bath tub. They would call it a shower in that case.

Related: What do you call a bathroom with no toilet?

@Fattie I think only people in UK, at least just the ones who post online here, are the only ones who think bathrooms can only be rooms with a bathtub in it. I will assure you bathroom is a common term to use in Australia too for referring to public toilets. Same thing can be said for fall and autumn. People think no one in USA calls fall "autumn", but I had heard autumn used as well, even though fall is a bit more common. Toilet still is the common term in Australia though.

@tchrist I wrote bathtub and bath for Americans, cause no American ever calls a bathtub a "bath". When an American says "bath", they would refer to the process of taking a bath, not the actual bathtub itself. Its really only in English where people care so much about what synonym you should use. This is never an issue in Spanish.

cheers @Megas , I don't 100% follow everything you're saying. How long have you visited Australia?

"Lavatory remains my favorite word, and this word is used commonly in airlines from USA."  Are you confusing the signage (ie, the small plastic sign with a light, on airliners) with what people say,  utterances?

No. Lavatory literally refers to the public restroom on planes. It doesnt sound gross like toilet, loo, or can and doesnt create issues on what the purpose of the room is like with bathroom, washroom, and restroom. Also, it doesnt tarnish someone's name like john or potty.

@Megas I think you'll find "bath" is a common term in the real estate industry, including in the US. For example, this zillow.com listing in LA.

That is to refer to the bathroom as a whole, not the bathtub itself.

@Fattie I moved here last summer, but I am in Sydney, which is probably the last place to feel the true Australian style of English. Way too many Americanisms here. At least half of the restaurants here call chips “fries” on their menus, and the amount of times I have seen stroller written more than pram.

@Megas To me, the term shower requires that there’s an actual shower there (a shower head that is or can be fixed above your head so water falls down on you from above). Not all bathtubs have that; some only have taps to fill the bowl, and I would never call those showers.

Voting to close this question as "opinion-based" as there cannot be a single correct answer - there are too many factors including etiquette for which there is another SE site. It's also quite clear from the OP's responses to answers that they are looking for validation rather than an answer.

What a great question! Unfortunately none of the apparent native speakers here seems inclined to compile a big table with all the different terms, usage nuances and regional preferences for each.
To pour more gasoline on the dumpster fire ... I wonder if anyone encountered O-O as an euphemism for either the room, appliance or act of using it.

@Astralbee Not true. I am looking for an answer, not an opinion. Unvote from closing this question.

Like many English terms, there are many right answers. Which term is commonly used depends on region, culture, and personal preference.
The following words are all synonymous for a room that has at least one toilet and sink, and that may or may not have a shower or bathtub as well:

Bathroom
Washroom
Restroom
Toilet
Lavatory (although this is really only used on airlines or in very formal contexts)
Ladies' Room/Men's Room (really only used when referring to a bathroom in a public/semi-public space such as a restaurant or shopping center. Not used to refer to a bathroom in a home.)

These words are interchangeable, and you'll hear a variety of them all over English-speaking regions. There is no functional difference between most of them, regardless of what specific equipment the room has in it. Notably, public bathrooms almost never have baths in them.
One note about toilet - the word comes from French where it originally meant small cloth. This became a reference for a room where one dressed, which became a room where one cleaned oneself. When indoor plumbing was invented, and chamber pots were replaced with flush toilets, the word was used as a euphemism, since it was just the name of the room they were put in. Calling a room a toilet isn't naming it after the most disgusting item in the room, it's the other way around!

It is since the toilet is the most disgusting appliance in the room. Why not call it washroom cause everyone washes their hands assuming when entering assuming they have hygiene?

@Megas: I think the point is that the appliance is named after the room, rather than the room being named after the appliance...

The English often use: Gents, too. I just saw it in a British police procedural, in a scene in a restaurant.

The word "toilet" is not interchangeable with "restroom" etc. in the U.S. I've been part of linguistic clashes in which an Australian said "She's in the toilet" and the American laughed or looked very confused. Americans also find signs like "No smoking in the toilet" funny, because toilet doesn't refer to the room in American English.

@LarsH That's very interesting. I wonder if there is a regional difference within the US or perhaps a generational/cultural difference? I live in the Northeast US, and while "bathroom" is definitely the most common phrase, I hear "toilet" used to refer to the room not rarely. Now that I think of it, that is mostly from young people though (millennials and younger). Maybe it's due to tv/movies?

"the toilet is the most disgusting appliance in the room" - but it represented a huge improvement in sanitation over the chamber pots we had before. But yes, that has a lot to do with the later coining of "bathroom" etc. Euphemism treadmills are just like that.

@Larsh If you ever went to dfw airport in Texas, then the signs say “toilets”, not bathrooms or restrooms. Restroom is interchangeable with toilet and bathroom, but bathroom is not interchangeable with restroom or toilet.

@Megas That's interesting. I lived in DFW and have been to the airport many times. I'm surprised to hear that the signs say "toilets," since the much more common airport signage in the US says "restrooms." It is possible for the signs to refer to the  appliances; or it may be a language shift as Friendly Racoon suggested. Or possibly an attempt to use more familiar terms for an international audience?

I have never heard “toilet” used conversationally in the US to describe the room with a toilet so I would strongly argue they’re not interchangeable in the US. It’s a bathroom or a restroom. Bathroom is more casual, restroom is more formal. So you might ask a friend where the bathroom is but you’d ask a stranger where the restroom is.

@bob Personally, toilet is interchangeable in the US for both bathroom and restroom, but yes, it is not as common as bathroom or restroom. However, It is safe to say all restrooms are toilets, but not all toilets are restrooms. As with bathrooms, all restrooms are bathrooms, but not all bathrooms are restrooms. As with bathrooms and toilets, not all bathrooms are toilets, and not all toilets are bathrooms. Even in commonwealth countries, it is hard to tell if a person is referring to the room or the applicance when they say toilet.

@LarsH In Australia, while toilet is the most common term to define a restroom, signs say restroom in all of the malls and shopping centres. Also, it can be hard to tell if they are referring to the actual appliance itself or the room when signs do say "toilet". Then, we got portable toilets, which is hard to tell if it is referring to the entire room itself or just the appliance.

In Oz. the most common word to use when you are going to the toilet is probably dunny. "I have to go to the dunny."  But that would be rarely used when denoting the room (like, "we are renovating the bathroom" or "we are going to paint the bathroom green"). If I'm not mistaken in Australia (what are we particularly discussing Australia?) the terms "washroom" and/or "w-c" surprisingly is used in the rare cases where you are distinguishing that from the "bathroom" (separate room/area with shower etc but no commode), ie when builders/tradesmen are talking about it.

A toilet (room) needs to have a toilet (fixture) in it
Because if you need to go to the toilet, you are going to be in trouble if the room you are directed to doesn’t have one. The toilet in “needing to go to the toilet” is neither the room nor the fixture - it’s the verb for the action of defecating/urinating. You can go to the toilet behind a tree if you need to. When an English speaker is going to the toilet, it’s the act of defecation/urination, not the walk to the fixture they are describing.
However, English is not just one language and words for rooms where bodily functions happen is one area where idiosyncratic euphemisms abound.
In North American English, it’s slightly rude to use “toilet” for the room: euphemisms used there are restroom or bathroom. Used in this context,
a bathroom, does not need to have a bath or shower in it - a room with just a toilet, with or without a basin, can be called a bathroom if the intention of the parties is clear. Even though the usage is not common outside North America, a visitor to your home asking to use the bathroom is understood to be asking to use the toilet, not to have a bath.
It’s perfectly fine to use toilet in British or Australian English and, at least in Australia, it’s the default to the extent that signs to public toilets will say “toilet”, with or without pictograms:

The name for the room came before the name for the fixture - both water closet (WC) and lavatory for the fixture pre-date using toilet.
Toilet entered English from French in the 16c and meant “a small piece of cloth”, particularly one in which you wrapped clothes or other cloth. It the  came to mean the small piece of cloth you put over your shoulders when dressing or shaving. Then the act of dressing or shaving itself. Then the room is which you did this. These rooms often had lavatories attached or incorporated, so it transferred from the room to the fixture. And finally from the fixture to the act of using it.
In certain circumstances, an English speaker could directly use the modern French word toilette, which took a different path and means washing yourself or adjusting hair or make up.  Which is why Eau de Toilette means perfume even though it’s literal translation “toilet water” means the water at the bottom of a toilet. Don’t get them confused!

@DaleM - my upper middle class lady friend told me she had the neighbours' young girls, lately arrived from South Africa, where they had lived since birth, for the afternoon. They were curious to see the dressing table in her bedroom. 'What's in that bottle?' one said. 'It's toilet water' she replied. 'YUK!' they both exclaimed (i.e. 'toilet' can be a class indicator in the UK; I call that stuff eau de toilette). My father called the jakes 'THE LAVATORY' in ringing tones.

In British English a bathroom always has a bath in it. We never say "bathroom" to mean toilet - if you say "I need to go to the bathroom" it sounds like you have a sudden urgent need to take a bath. (At least this was the case ~10 years ago when I last lived in the UK, maybe it's changed now.)

@N.Virgo if you say it in an American accent, people will probably know what you mean, though.

@N.Virgo - times have changed in the UK; I heard a lady say that her neighbour lets his dog 'go to the bathroom in the street'.

@N Virgo That might be just Britain, but in Australia at least, people will use bathroom sometimes to differentiate between the fixture and the room. Also, not everyone who goes to the public toilet room actually used the fixture. Some may just go to wash their hands or throw rubbish away in the bin. This is where washroom comes to play, and this is better than toilet. You could also call it binroom or rubbishroom cause there are bins present and you can throw rubbish away.
In America, people could use toilet too, but most stick with restroom.

I was never confused about this before, but now I am. :-)

Your origin story of toilet lets me see that it's related to "towel", the modern word for the piece of cloth.

@Mari-LouA: I determined it by living in the UK since birth and being surrounded by people who did the same ;). The vast majority of people I know would say "sink" for both what you find in a bathroom and what you find in a kitchen, but it may of course vary by region/class/other factors. I'm not sure whether dishwashers are a factor but I hope you get one one day :-)

IKEA UK/IE uses "Bathroom sink", and I would use the word to the exclusion of most others. https://www.ikea.com/gb/en/cat/bathroom-sinks-20723/

“A bathroom, however, does not need to have a bath or shower in it ” — This may be regional.  In UK English (at least, to my ears), it would sound odd to call a room without a bath or shower a ‘bathroom’ — just as it would sound odd to call a room without a lavatory a ‘toilet’.

Toronto, Canada: the fixture in a bathroom (or washroom, but almost never "restroom" - that's American) is absolutely a "(bathroom) sink", and people are likely not to understand if you say "(wash)basin". I can't even recall the last time I've heard the latter.

If you are in Singapore, toilet is the term most will use. No restroom, bathroom, or washroom.

@N.Virgo that's utterly incorrect. It's common parlance in the north of the UK at least. "I just need to pop to the bathroom" is something you might hear literally daily to indicate that they need to use the toilet

So this really is the worst place possible for English learners, isn't it?

@roganjosh I lived in Leeds for about 5 years in the 90s and I'm confident I never heard anyone say that, they would always just have said toilet or loo. Like I said, it could be different now.

@N.Virgo "loo" would definitely be more common but "bathroom" would be universally understood in Manchester and is used. I don't know whether it classifies as a euphemism. This question has been quite interesting to introspect on how different people refer to the toilet

I agree with @roganjosh . At least in the north of England, the room in a house with a bath and toilet in is called the bathroom. If it doesn't have a bath (or, marginally, at least a shower) it's called the toilet. You can go to the toilet in the bathroom (if it really is a bathroom), or you can go to the toilet in the toilet, if it's a dedicated room. It's been like this since at least the 1970s. Washbasins are usually called basins or, informally, sinks.
Everyone will understand if you use these words differently. As you can tell, it's all variable even among native speakers.

Restroom makes sense only that people sometimes need a toilet break, and break is a synonym for rest. Again, why not call it toilet room to help differentiate between the room and appliance?

In some places, yes
I teach at an international boarding school in the US.
My Australian students will absolutely ask me if they can go to the toilet.  For my yankee ears, that does sound, if not vulgar, at least too direct.  Some of my Chinese students will also say toilet, but not all - I think it depends on who taught them English - they may have had an Australian teacher in Hong Kong, an American teacher in Shanghai, an Indian teacher in Taipei, etc.
My domestic students overwhelmingly say "bathroom", but a few from very formal families and / or old money will say "washroom".
My grandparents (raised in turn of the century upstate New York) did say "water closet" or "wc" [double-you-cee] so this use was endemic to the US at one point but I imagine went out with television.  They also had a "davenport" in their family room, an "icebox" in their kitchen, and put on "rubbers" when it rained, none of which would be recognized as such by any of my students.

I went to one of the poshest boarding schools out there though now it is a day school. And the only people who said washroom were southern/western. Never northern.  I personally have never heard an old-money northerner say it.  Fat lot of good that school did me. Except that no one can now outsnob me. Too much education but no money. Haha  One minor story: The housemother said we weren't to pick up chicken with our fingers. My mother (a southern lady, fried chicken, wink, wink) said, it's okay to do so with one hand.  That shut the housemother up. :)

Anyway, you have a definite teaching point there.

@Lambie At least traditionally, southerners have more formal manners than anywhere else in the US.  Although I think such regionalisms are decreasing.

Well, I can't even fathom what teaching at a boarding school would be like today.  So kudos to you, friend.

"wc" sounds posh and continental European to me now.

I've always understood "wc" to be a Britishism. I've heard "washroom" occasionally but not enough to derive a pattern to who uses it. My grandmother used to call a refrigerator an "icebox". I have no idea what a "davenport" is, I'll have to look it up. I'm an old man and I still talk about "film" when I mean "video". I'll have to think if I use other anachronisms.

@Jay A davenport may have been predominantly regional at least in origin, namely the Inland North dialect of the Great Lakes states as well as parts of New England. It seems to have receded to those regions again today. Perhaps you are not from one of those regions? If so, then just wait till you come to the quaintness of chesterfields for certain sorts of ottomans, or bubblers for a certain kind of drinking fountain. :)

Since you say your students now would not recognise the davenport your grandparents had in their family room “as such”, are we to understand that they would understand davenport as something else, presumably a writing desk? I’m not quite school age anymore, but if someone said they had a davenport in their house, I would assume they meant the sofa at least 99% of the time.

@JanusBahsJacquet In the case of 'davenport', they would have no idea what the word meant.  In the case of 'rubbers', they would think that the only possible thing it could refer to was erasers (UK) or condoms (US).

What did they mean by rubber? In Australia, rubber is a term for what US calls "eraser". Anyways, why do Americans seem to cringe at calling a room a toilet? What if they called it "toilet room"? Would that solve this dilemma?

@Megas (1/2) My grandparents used "rubbers" as the word for what you might know as galoshes, slipper galoshes, overshoes, or bad-weather shoes. Of course, my students wouldn't know what any of these were either, but they would recognize that they didn't know the word rather than confuse it with something else. When my Aussie students ask to go to the toilet, I don't recognize it as a room; to me, toilet is just the fixture. They are asking 'Can I go [to the room that has a toilet]. But what I hear is 'Can I go [sit on the commode]'.  Sure you can, but just tell me you want to use the bathroom.

@Megas (2/2) Yes, If someone asked me whether they could go to the 'toilet room', clearly indicating they meant the room and not the fixture, it would sound less vulgar.  But it would also sound strange, because no one uses that expression - we use washroom or bathroom.

How does this sound more vulgar than saying “john” or “can”? Also, it’s hard to tell if your Aussie students are referring to the room itself? Chances are they are talking about the appliance as in Australia, toilet is also the term for the applicance, and people do say bathroom sometimes. In Australia, slippers are called thongs.

@Kirt Oh, I see. Yeah, rubbers would need specific context to make sense to me; I would expect them to be called rubber boots or wellies normally (not quite the same thing, of course, but things like galoshes and spats don’t really exist anymore).

@tchrist I grew up in New York and spent most of my life in Ohio and Michigan. Now I live in the Philippines, which is about as far away from Michigan as you can get and still be on Planet Earth. There are some very different regionalisms here which cause me great amusement.

@kirt I grew up in New York in the 1960s through 1980s, and the term "rubbers" meant a rubber outer shoe that you put over your regular shoes to protect them from rain or mud. Yes, it could also mean a condom. I had a teacher in high school who was from the UK and used "rubber" to mean "eraser", which the class found very amusing because we all thought "condom".

@Megas RE "calling a room a toilet" Why is any word considered crude or vulgar? Why is "defecate" perfectly good in the most polite company or formal setting, but "s**t" is not? Words just take on meanings and connotations, and while one might learn something by studying the history, all around it doesn't matter. In the US, we just don't call the room a "toilet" or a "toilet room". That's the name of the fixture. We call the room a "bathroom" or "restroom". Calling it a "toilet room" sounds a little crude to me and I think to most Americans. It just is.

@Megas FWIW, here in the Philippines, what Americans call "sandals" or "thongs" are called "slippers". I find it quite strange to see a big sign that says "Slippers" and then below it are a bunch of sandals, but whatever. Or, and everyone wears sandals/slippers around the house. In fact many people have 3 pairs: one to wear outside, one to wear around the house in general, and one to wear in the bathroom. Which here is called a "comfort room".

I had never heard anyone in America call slippers "thongs". I only heard of this word in Australia. In America, people just say slippers, sandals, or flip flops, and for the ones with a high-heels, a high-heel. I had never heard "rubber" used to define shoes or even a condom. I just learned a few months ago online rubber is US slang for condom while in Australia, it is the word for eraser.

I have never been to Australia and so I don't know the common terminology there.
In the US, a "toilet" is the fixture that you use to dispose of bodily waste. The room it is in is generally called a "bathroom", even if it doesn't have a bath tub. "Restroom" is also common, especially for the room with toilets in a public place, like a store or restaurant. Yes, someone might say, "I have to go to the toilet", but this means they need to eliminate waste, they're referring to the fixture, and not particularly to the room. It's more common to say "I have to go to the bathroom", probably because this is considered more polite. Occasionally people will say, "I have to pee" or "I have to poop", but this is generally considered just a bit crude. "I have to s**t" or "I have to take a s**t" is also used, but this is definitely crude and would not normally be said in "polite company".
For what it's worth, I now live in the Philippines, where the accepted term for the room is "comfort room". "Bathroom" and "restroom" are recognized, probably because of American influence. So if a foreigner asks, "Where's your bathroom?", this would be readily understood, but few natives would say that.

I believe the correct word in Australia is 'dunny'.

It’s hard to tell. Some could refer to the room. There are portable toilets. Most would call it a restroom though. In Australia, the fixture is also called a toilet.

@Micheal Dunny is slang for toilet. I haven’t heard this used by anyone there. Most would call it a toilet, or sometimes, a bathroom. One person said “men’s room” to me and another said “washroom” to me. Washroom is Canadian, while men’s room is American.

@Megas I've never heard "dunny". Perhaps that is Australian slang, but I'm not aware of it being used in the US. Yes, "men's room" and "ladies' room" are terms used in the US for public restrooms, where there are separate rooms for men and women. I've never heard someone refer to a bathroom in a house, where there is only one for both sexes, as a "men's room". Though if someone said, "I have to go to the men's room" and then went to a common room, I doubt anyone would think much of it. Amusingly, the obviously parallel to "men's room" would be "women's room", but you rarely hear that.

Dunny is an Australian slang like john and can are for the toilet in America. However, in Australia, most stick with toilet, but occasionally will say bathroom if they don’t need to use the toilet. Restroom is written on signs in shopping centres.

@Megas I've heard "john" and "can" as slang terms for a room with a toilet. I'd understand what he meant if someone said, "I'm going to the can". But they're not words that anyone I know would use. As you say, if it's in someone's house, it's a "bathroom". If it's in a store or other public place, it's a "restroom".

No, only use toilet if there's a toilet in there.

I don't see that anything more needs to be said on such a simple question?  Why are we all so prolix?

So, is it okay to call the room a toilet instead of a bathroom even if it has a bath or shower in it?

Your question was: is it right to call a room which has a toilet, but also has a bath/shower, a toilet? The answer is "yes". No matter how many times you ask, and are told the answer, and you disagree with the answer, the answer is simply yes.

lling you the tradition and commonality in English. There is no logic whatsoever to any language, it's just commonality and tradition.

It seems weird cause every country calls it a bathroom. I can understand the public restrooms being called a toilet, and honestly, I would find it weird if someone from USA finds it crass or impolite, but why call the room with a bath/shower as well after the most disgusting applicane in the room. Call it a sinkroom or showerroom. Call it a washroom cause everyone who goes inside this room washes themselves. Canada uses the best term.

@Megas Language doesn't have to be logical or polite. The answer is yes, people frequently use toilet to refer to a room with a bath and a toilet. Whether or not you like that, is completely out of scope

@Megas my friend, you know it's a funny thing, a very common on this site, which is funny... A person will arrive and they will say the following.. So in English, it is X. This is incredibly illogical. So is X correct? Then, 150 completely native English speakers from all around the world will get on the site and say yes, X. Of the 150 people many are professors, well-known novelists, newspaper editors, producers, etc. And then what the OP says in reply is: surely X is not logical??? As you can see it's quite funny! It happens over and over on this site literally two or three times a day.

In some ways, to make but one example, in my opinion the basic parts of speech and are  near no longer existing in English; in English now people can and do use literally any word as a verb, adverb, adjective; conversely, what we used to think of as verbs are used as nouns with no thought. You can't really discuss slang in English anymore because the language is so incredibly degenerate that it's meaningless to say oh that's not the 'correct' form.. Given this incredible crackhead -like feature of modern English, asking a question like "where is the toilet" is very misplaced.

Yes!
A toilet is (today) generally understood to be a specific appliance, but that does not match its etymology, which could easily have been Googled.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toilet#Etymology
The word comes from the French for a cloth used in grooming. Over time it became synonymous with the room used for grooming, which in time acquired facilities for washing and, yes, disposing of bodily wastes.
Historic English usage has always been hung-up on anything related to body function and has employed euphemisms for the lot of it, including needs for urination and defecation.
Hence, the modern flush toilet quickly became a reference to the appliance itself and is so known today.
Nevertheless, the older sense of the toilet as a reference to the room itself remains in many people’s vocabulary, and is no more offensive than “water closet” or “lavatory” or “bath room”, all terms references to the wash room function, wherein a modern toilet fixture may also be found (in Western countries, at least. In Japan, for example, the fixture is kept in a room separate from the washing room(s)).
Even for those not familiar with the room reference, there is always a sink near a toilet fixture. And even when people think the word “toilet” is low-brow, they still have a pretty good idea what kind of room you are aiming to find.
If in doubt, let someone know you are unfamiliar with the local vocabulary and ask them what they call the room with the toilet in it.
If you are actually looking to bathe or shower, say so.

Sorry, but how are bathroom, lavatory, and water closet offensive?

Uh, they're not. How on earth did you infer I make any such claim?

In the US the most common polite names for a room containing a toilet the I’ve heard used conversationally are “bathroom”, “restroom”, “ladies room”, and “men’s room”. “Bathroom” is more casual, while “restroom”, “men’s room”, and “ladies room” are more formal. So you might ask a friend where the bathroom is but you’d ask a stranger where the restroom is or where the men’s room or ladies room is. Toilet would sound odd if not a little crass if used to describe the room and not just the commode itself.

Lets be real. Its hard to tell if people in any country mean the room or just the appliance when saying toilet. Also, why would it sound crass in just the US to use the word that literally all the other countries use? Ladies room and mens room arent that formal in the US. I do agree I heard bathroom and restroom used the most there, with restroom for the public toilets and bathroom for the ones with a bath.

Toilet to my ears sounds crass (I know it’s not elsewhere in the world, but it sounds that way to me as an American) because it highlights the object that we’ll be using, and thus what will be done there not just the room itself. In the US we kind of go out of our way to avoid saying the purpose of the room at least when using polite speech. We don’t rest in a restroom and bathing isn’t its primary function either.

I meant bathing isn’t a bathroom’s primary function. Wrote that last part wrong.

Neither is using a toilet a primary function either. However, one should always wash themselves if they have hygenine, which is why I love washroom more than restroom, toilet, or bathroom. I will admit restroom does sound weird, and even bathroom does for public toilets. Toilet is a ridiculous word though. This one time, my mom was talking to this lady working in my residence building, and she kept calling the room in my unit a toilet despite having a shower, while my mom kept calling it a bathroom. It showed how cringe the lady saying toilet sounded. Toilet is only for public bathrooms.

I deny the premise of the question.  I have never heard the asserted usage (that 'toilet' is used to refer to the room containing a bath) in this context. I've lived in Australia for more than six decades (since I was born apart from a few months overseas), in three states - and have visited more. I encountered no regional variation in usage.
If an Australian asks for a toilet, they specifically want a room with a toilet in it, wherever that happens to be. The existence or nonexistence of a bath in that room will be immaterial. If they want a bath, they'll certainly ask for a bathroom.
If an Australian says "I need to go to the toilet" they certainly want to end up in a room with a toilet fixture in it because they want to use that specific fixture.
A room with a bath in it will nearly always be called a bathroom but can have other names (e.g. a small bathroom coming off a bedroom might be called an en suite; it might nevertheless have a small bath in it, or perhaps just a shower). The toilet fixture, if a room with a bath includes one is itself a called a toilet, but I'm quite sure I've never heard the term used to refer to the room itself. If you point into the room with a bath in it and ask "what's this room called?" you won't get "toilet" unless perhaps you just asked about a toilet.
If you say to an Australian "where's the toilet?" they may point to the bathroom, not because they would call the room a toilet but because that's where the toilet happens to be in that house.
Many Australian homes (my own included) include a room that might be called the toilet (among other names), but a room called by that name doesn't contain a bath; it will have a toilet fixture, and may include a sink, or perhaps a room with a sink suitable for washing hands may be adjacent to it (perhaps a laundry room, for example, which are common in Australia).
I've had overseas visitors ask for the bathroom when they actually want the toilet, which seems odd, since that's maybe a 50-50 shot here unless you're in a unit (apartment). Those two things have only coincided in a very small number of the places I've lived (I vastly prefer it that way; I like the room containing my toothbrush, razor, band aids and so forth well away from where the toilet facility is if I have any choice). If they're the sort of person that can take a joke, I'll direct them to the room they asked for - one containing a bath - rather than ask whether they actually want a room with a toilet in it ... unless the mission appears urgent, naturally.
I've had no difficulty getting to a room with a toilet in it in either the UK or the US by simply asking where the toilet is. Common usage will typically prefer other terms but the word is understood and avoids any possible confusion about what you seek.

I live in Sydney now. Bathroom is common here for people to say, though toilet is the most common for public toilet rooms. However, restroom is written on signs in shopping centers. Without adding the word “room” in front of “toilet”, it’s hard to tell if the person is referring to the appliance or the room itself. In the USA, people sometimes say they need to go to the toilet, but there, bathroom and restroom are used a lot more than in Australia. I am from New South Wales in the Sydney area.

I live in Sydney too. I've been here since 1981. Across a variety of suburbs. If you ask for a bathroom somewhere public, of course nobody will assume you wish to take a bath, especially if you appear to be from overseas. If you're in a private home and you ask where the bathrooms are, those rooms will contain facilities for bathing unless they think you're actually asking for a toilet (which they may if you're from overseas). The rooms with baths may contain a toilet as well, or they might not, but any such inclusion won't make the room with a bath into anything but a bathroom. ...

... ctd If you ask where the toilet is, you'll certainly be directed to a room with a toilet facility, whether or not it has a bath. If it has a bath, the room is still a bathroom.

Yeah. I see signs saying toilets most of the time, which I assume would be referring to the appliance and not the room itself cause the sign says “toilets”, not “toilet”, cause Australia too has toilet as the term for the appliance, and bathroom is used too for the public toilet room. I had heard washroom once and even “men’s room”. The first is Canadian while the second is USA.

Summary: Toilet would be universally understood and generally considered correct, but I have always understood 'Water Closet' to be the standard, totally specific, non-slang word for a toilet.
'Toilet' certainly is in common use in many places for a bathroom without a toilet, and is considered to be idiomatic, standard, polite English. The terms used for a toilet and the room in which it is housed do vary quite a lot, as some of the other answers have made clear. Here is a quite good list.
It is much more common to find a room with a bath/shower plus a toilet than a room with just a bath/shower. You do see 'shower rooms' in gyms, however, which would not be called a toilet.
Pedantically, and very formally, 'toilet' is a euphemism - it originally referred to the room in which one ‘made one's toilet’ - the process of washing, arranging your hair, putting on perfume, and so on. It can be considered very roughly equivalent to 'bathroom', 'washroom', or 'lavatory', which all literally mean the room in which you clean yourself. I have always understood 'Water Closet' to be the standard, totally specific, non-slang word for a toilet, and in at least some countries it is commonly seen on signs in the abbreviation 'WC'. This term would only be used for a room without a bath/shower, however, which leaves the name of a room with both a bit ambiguous.

In the US I never heard or said 'water closet', not even knowing what it meant. I've never encountered that phrase in popular novels. I don't think it is idiomatic American English. I also did not perceive 'toilet' as polite. Are those usages UK English?

Yep, I had never heard water closet anywhere. It’s a British usage I believe, but I think most in British would call it a toilet. Loo is another informal slang for toilet in Britain.
Why is toilet impolite?

@Megas Toilet is usually considered perfectly polite (as polite as talking about toilets can be!). 99% of the time people will consider it a normal word to use, even if you're referring to a room without an actual toilet in it (though as you're aware there are a lot of regional slang terms). 'Water closet' in full is pretty rare, but you do see WC signs moderately often, and not just in Britain!

@piejo 'Polite' as in not rude, vulgar, slang, working-class or otherwise uncouth. You could be confident of using it without offending anyone, in any conversation about toilets. In a specifically British context, it's quite middle-class, so not really polite as in 'polite society', but it's more polite than e.g. 'shithouse', more formal than 'loo', and less silly-sounding than 'I'm going to see a man about a dog'. I had a look in the OED, and it says the use of 'toilet' originated in America and was common in the 19th century, so I expect the older word (WC) would be extremely rare.

I would like to emphasise that this answer is quite pedantic, probably more than is ideal for an answer to learners. Generally people will understand what you mean if you use any word for toilet - or just an embarrassed "can I use your, um..."

water closet is archaic! :) toilet is never impolite, even in the States.

People in occasional cases do call the public restroom in USA a toilet.  Never heard water closet be used anywhere. That’s a new one.
Brits use loo as an informal term though.

I'm reasonably sure that even Americans would have encountered a "WC" sign on doors to toilets? That's what it stands for - "Water Closet"

As someone who used to live in America for most of my life, I have never encountered this even once, and I had been to 30 states there. I never heard this anywhere in my life. Water closet is an informal british term for a public toilet, but most people would just call it a toilet for public and a bathroom when at home. I have seen "toilets" written a few times, like at DFW Airport in Texas for instance, which means people will know what you mean.
